# Rounding up individual elements in an array and sorting them afterwards

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, double, rounding

I am trying to solve for:

Original array elements:
[0 16 27 73 55]

- first round them up
  0-> 0 stays;
  16 is rounded up to 20 and converted to 2.
  27 is rounded up to 30 and converted to 3.
  73 is rounded down to 70 and converted to 7.
  55 is rounded up to 60 and converted to 6.
- second I short the converted "new"elements and get an OUTPUT:

[0,2,3,6,7]

if any new elements are the same, both enetries are kept for isntance [0,2,3,6,6,7]

Many thanks for your thoughst and support.

Comment: And how far have you gotten solving that problem? Where are you stuck exactly and which part is giving you problems? You should show your code that you have written so far and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I am stuck how to round up and convert. I was thinking of dividing all elements (doubles) by 10 and then rounding up to whole numbers; but not sure if this is the most elegant approach

Comment: I would loop through your original array and each step of the way perform the rounding you mentioned.  If you need to keep the original array, you can store those rounded values in a new one.  Then, there is a built in sort function you can run on the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on the clarification comment you made, it sounds like you don't know how to approach rounding to the nearest multiple of 10.  If you don't want to use float/decimal solutions, you can use "mod" and I'd write a function like...

```
public class Main {
  static int NearMult10(int srcVal) {
    int remainder = srcVal % 10;

    if (remainder < 5) { return srcVal - remainder; }
    else { return srcVal + (10 - remainder); }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("rounded...");
    int[] srcList = { 3, 6, 12, 18, 37, 81, 108 };
    int srcCount = srcList.length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < srcCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("src: " + srcList[i] + " => result: " + NearMult10(srcList[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

And just use that "NearMult10" method.  The result of that example code looks like...

```
rounded...
src: 3 => result: 0
src: 6 => result: 10
src: 12 => result: 10
src: 18 => result: 20
src: 37 => result: 40
src: 81 => result: 80
src: 108 => result: 110
```

You can call the sort method on whatever array you build.

Comment: many thanks Kevin, this was exactly my stumbling point. appreciate your time and the solution you provided. Making my first steps into java here. Again - appreciate yr help.

Comment: If it worked as your solution, can you mark it as the correct answer please?  :)